# How to set value in data-plugin-options from Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, html5-canvas

I want to know how can I set the value of a control which is using data-plugin-options to set the values for a gauge control.

I have this html markup:

```
<div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="demo-label">Average Speed</div>
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="gauge-chart">
                            <canvas id="gaugeBasic" width="180" height="110" data-plugin-options='{ "value": 2150, "maxValue": 3000 }'></canvas>

                            <label id="gaugeBasicTextfield"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Using another different control, which is Angular directive, I'm able to declare and set the value I need like this

```
<ridge-speedometer x-val="AverageSpeed"/>
```

Now instead of that control I want to use the markup above, and where the value of 2150 is currently, I want to use the *AverageSpeed* value.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AverageSpeed to be available on the UI, you need to attach it to the controller, or $scope like so:

```
$scope.AverageSpeed = 2150;
```

And what you should really do for cleanliness sake is extract that object from data-plugin-options to your controller as well, like so:

```
$scope.options = {
    value: $scope.AverageSpeed,
    maxValue: 3000
}
```

And then plug it in to your UI as such:

```
<canvas id="gaugeBasic" width="180" height="110" data-plugin-options="options"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thx @Brant, I'm able to get the scope values as you can see from the screenshot but the control doesn't accept that binding https://i.gyazo.com/da795a442a80f5b3e29b1a6822e43d0f.png. This is what I'm using <canvas id="gaugeBasic" width="180" height="110" data-plugin-options="options"></canvas>

Comment: Do you have some JQuery running before it gets those options?>

Comment: yes jquery.js is run first, then the gauge.js and last is angular.js @Brant thx for your help

Comment: Angular should come first in all of them if I'm not mistaken, have you reversed the order?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95266/discussion-between-laziale-and-brant).

Comment: pls check the chat window if you're around